# Check if device exists before creating it in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create several devices like `/dev/zero`, `/dev/null` etc. using following code:

```
- name: mknod devices in default chroot
  shell: "mknod -m 0666 {{ item.localdev }} c 1 {{ item.localvalue }}"
  args:
    creates:{{ item.localdev }}
  with_items:
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/null',    localvalue: '3'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/random',  localvalue: '8'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/urandom', localvalue: '9'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/zero',    localvalue: '5'}
  tags: mknod_devices
```

It works when I execute it for the first time, but second and every another time it fails with message that certain device is already present. I've checked another syntax for `creates` parameter and I've hardcoded value like that:

```
creates: /var/www/dev/null
```

And now ansible do not fail but obviously this is not a solution. Is there a way to put variable into `creates` parameter?

**EDIT**: to be clear, as a workaround I could also use following `shell` syntax (tested, works), but I'm looking for a cleaner solution

```
shell: "if [[ ! -e {{ item.localdev }} ]]; then mknod -m 0666 {{ item.localdev }} c 1 {{ item.localvalue }}; else echo \"{{ item.localdev }} exists, skipping\"; fi"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command module instead of the shell module, which supports the "creates" function.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes

  tasks:
  - name: mknod devices in default chroot
    command: "mknod -m 0666 {{ item.localdev }} c 1 {{ item.localvalue }} creates={{ item.localdev }}"
    with_items:
      - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/null',    localvalue: '3'}
      - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/random',  localvalue: '8'}
      - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/urandom', localvalue: '9'}
      - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/zero',    localvalue: '5'}
    tags: mknod_devices
```

This will create the directories if they do not exist and do nothing if they do.

Comment: This answer wrongly explains the problem. Both [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) and [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) support `creates` parameter. The problem in question is wrong syntax not wrong module usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trivially simple:

- you need a space in between the parameter and the value in `creates:{{ item.localdev }}`
- after adding the space you need to quote `{{ item.localdev }}`

The correct syntax is:

```
- name: mknod devices in default chroot
  shell: "mknod -m 0666 {{ item.localdev }} c 1 {{ item.localvalue }}"
  args:
    creates: "{{ item.localdev }}"
  with_items:
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/null',    localvalue: '3'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/random',  localvalue: '8'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/urandom', localvalue: '9'}
    - { localdev: '/var/www/dev/zero',    localvalue: '5'}
  tags: mknod_devices
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you deleted your negative comment on my answer. If you want to call out someones answer at least defend your reasoning. I tested my answer prior to posting and it does not return a syntax error. Additionally, it works as the OP wanted it. I admit I did overlooked his syntax error but both answers are still correct. The output from is in fact "mknod -m 0666 /var/www/dev/zero c 1 5" NOT "mknod -m 0666 /var/www/dev/zero c 1 5 creates=/var/www/dev/null" as you suggest.